# 71 confirmations?

Tags: confirmations

I'm not too worried if this doesn't work for some reason as it's not much money but can someone tell me what this spent thing means? It's been about 10 hours https://blockchain.info/tx-index/e146c2c298d39172c189aefc274cd644890ba85f38826c9064cb86d50a6df415

Comment: Have you checked whether it is your address?

Answer (score 1):

This means that the bitcoin network has settled 71 times that the transaction you have referred to did occur and is valid. With so many confirmations, the transaction is practically impossible to change or reverse.

Comment: yeah it's just that nothing is in my wallet :/

Comment: @jay: Are you using Bitcoin Core, and is it still synchronizing (i.e. catching up to the network's state)?

Comment: @Murch multibit

Comment: idk what to do lmaoo it's whatever tho